# Why does diesel have a higher energy density than gasoline?

Tags: organic-chemistry, combustion, fuel

One of the primary reasons why hydrocarbons produce energy is the production of water during the combustion process.

I've been trying to find out why diesel is considered to have a higher energy density compared to gasoline and I can think of a couple of reasons:

- Higher molar mass (more carbon/hydrogen to burn)
- Easier to burn diesel since it is heavier (weaker bonds)

I think I'm on the right path but I don't have a clear picture of the situation.

Comment: If your question were about Diesel and Otto engines, from the perspective of *physics* I would like to add to your picture drawn that the compression/decompression ratio in a Diesel engine is much higher than a Otto engine; as the mix auto-ignites, there are no spark plugs necessary (glowing plugs are a different story).  In terms of the Carnot cycle, this is one contribution why a Diesel engine may be more efficient than an Otto engine in terms of converting chemical energy into mechanical energy.

Comment: related https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/69425/how-does-biodiesel-have-so-much-energy-density

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Diesel and gasoline have roughly the same energy per unit mass ([lower heating value](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Lower_heating_value)), about $41~\pu{MJ/kg}$).

The density of diesel is about $833~\pu{kg/m^3}$ compared to $740~\pu{kg/m^3}$ for gasoline. This gives diesel about 13% higher energy density per volume.

Comment: The actual structure of the hydrocarbons themselves don't contribute to the energy per unit mass, but their willingness to undergo combustion?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by the term "willingness to undergo combustion". But the structure of the hydrocarbons has influence on their heating values. E.g. methane > ethane > propane > butane > pentane (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_of_combustion#Heat_of_combustion_tables)